# node How to to get vars into require modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was just wondering whether there is any best/recommended way to get variables into required modules with node js? What should be avoided?

So far I know of the following ways:

by function parameters

```
mymodule = require('./modules/mymodule.js')(varA,varB);
... and ...
module.exports = function (varA, varB) {}
```

by don't know how to call it?

```
mymodule = require('./modules/mymodule.js').varA;
... and ...
module.exports = function (varA, varB) {
    console.log(varA)
}
```

through a setter class

```
mymodule = require('./modules/mymodule');
... and ...
module.exports = function () {
    var that = this;
    this.varA = null;
    this.setVarA = function(varA) {that.varA = varA:}
}
```

Thx, I really appreciate your expertice

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what I think you are trying to do is to create an object in your module with a setter and a getter:

```
function MyObject( varA ) {
  this._varA = varA;
}

MyObject.prototype.setVarA = function( varA ) {
  this._varA = varA;
}

MyObject.prototype.getVarA = function() {
  return this._varA;
}

module.exports = MyObject;
```

and to use

```
var MyObject = require( './myModule' );

var myObjectInstance = new MyObject( "someValue" );

console.log( myObjectInstance.getVarA() ); //logs someValue

myObjectInstance.setVarA( "anotherValue" );

console.log( myObjectInstance.getVarA() ); //logs someOtherValue
```

This MDN [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) article has some good info related to this.

The method above might be overkill for what you are looking for though, so you could do something simpler with just an object literal:

```
module.exports = function( varA ) {
  return {
    varA : varA
  };
};
```

and to use

```
var myModule = require( './myModule' )( "someValue" );
console.log( myModule.varA ); // logs someValue
```